# Transfer a question

Tags: support, status-completed

Not sure if this is the right place to ask for not. Would it be possible to transfer my question https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/71429/family-relationships to the new closed beta http://genealogy.stackexchange.com?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Migrated to Genealogy.SE.

<s>It's not showing up in the mod migration menu right now—might be caching or might be that we can't migrate until the target site is in public beta. I'll follow up on this in a few days; in future, however, you can simply flag your post with a message as to where it would fit better and we'll handle that for you.</s>